# Convert timestamp to local time T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, select

I'm writing a query in t-sql to convert timestamp to local time, 
and don't know how to do it properly based on following columns: 
time: **'29/02/2020 12:02:05'** and
timezone : **'Europe/Paris'**

Example Result
function('29/02/2020 12:02:05','Paris') should return ’29/02/2020 13:02:05’ corresponding internal timestamp representation.

Thanks

Comment: What version of SQL Server? Do you have a mapping table that has what the UTC +/- is for all of your timezones? If not, you'll need to create one. Why did you choose to store the timezone separately and not use `datetimeoffset`?

Comment: Also, why would `29/02/2020 12:02:05` return `2007-11-11 00:59:00`? Those dates are completely different.

Comment: so it's db that i use just to get data, need just to convert based on UTC+0, sql 2016

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running SQL Server 2016 or newer, you can use [`at time zone`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016).

To turn an utc datetime to a given timezone, you can do:

```
select t.ts at time zone 'utc' at time zone t.tz from t
```

Where `ts` is the column that holds the `datetime`, and `tz` is a valid destination timezone (you can find the list of supported timezones in [sys.time_zone_info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-time-zone-info-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)).

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c167496aac92218ca86230cbfbdd102f)**:

```
with t as (
    select 
        cast('2020-02-29 12:02:05' as datetime) ts,
        'Central European Standard Time' tz
)
select ts, tz, ts at time zone 'utc' at time zone tz ts_in_paris from t
GO
```

```
ts                      | tz                             | ts_in_paris                
:---------------------- | :----------------------------- | :--------------------------
2020-02-29 12:02:05.000 | Central European Standard Time | 2020-02-29 13:02:05.0000000
```